# How to setup a Subdomain of an existing domain in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I created an Instance (Windows Server 2016) within AWS and the domain URL amazon gave me as below:

```
ec2-10-212-103-15.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Then, to create a subdomain I went to Route53 (https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home#Dashboard)
Here is the picture of my configurations:
[image]

But I still cannot open http://uat.ec2-10-212-103-15.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

*(Note: The IP is made-up)*

What do I need more to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're getting it wrong. Route53 is for custom domains you purchase from any of source (GoDaddy, Amazon, Namecheap naming a few).

The URL **ec2-10-212-103-15.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com** you've mentioned isn't the domain name. It is actually DNS to your server. If your instance is not behind a NAT gateway then you can directly access it through **ec2-10-212-103-15.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com** else you need to place a load balancer with public accessibility or place instance behind an internet gateway.